# Neat Formatted Test Cases Error Output for Python Django

Tags: python, django

I am running my nose test cases for my django app using

```
python manage.py test
```

However, when I get an output a particular test case error, the output is like this:

```
>         Error Message
>     exit__ six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback) File "/home/ubuntu/Envs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py",
> line 53, in execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) File
> "/home/ubuntu/Envs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py",
> line 452, in execute return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query,
> params) 'UNIQUE constraint failed: apixyz_.budsadsinesds_id,
> api_user_id\n-------------------- >> begin captured logging <<
> --------------------\npy.warnings: WARNING: /home/ubuntu/Envs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:883:
> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField BusinessMetrics.from_date received
> a naive datetime (2017-05-29 11:35:13.639105) while time zone support
> is active.\n RuntimeWarning)\n\npy.warnings: WARNING:
> /home/ubuntu/Envs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:883:
> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeMetrics.from_date received a naive datetime
> (2017-05-29 11:35:13.647704) while time zone support is active.\n
> RuntimeWarning)\n\npy.warnings: WARNING:
> /home/ubuntu/Envs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:883:
> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeMetrics.from_date received a naive datetime
> (2017-05-29 11:35:13.656736) while time zone support is active.\n
```

(Pasted a sample here but it looks better only because I added the lines as quote and code block)

And this is not really readable. Can I set some option so that traceback is more readable and \n changes to next line automatically?